# What gender is Osana Najimi? Are they genderfluid?

Tags: komi-cant-communicate

What gender does Osana Najimi specifically fit in? I know that Osana fits somewhere in the non-binary spectrum since there's a word for everything nowadays, but the question is where?

Comment: Hideyoshi (baka to test) ?

Comment: AFAIK it is even unknown whether Najimi is biologically male or female.